# Citizen Patrol bug?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, badges

I never flagged a post or comment as offensive/spam, and yet I now have the "Citizen Patrol" badge? Is it an errant click or a bug?

Comment: There is some discussion across the stacks on this issue.  see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78797/are-you-sure-citizen-patrol-is-fixed-right

Comment: @RD01: Thanks. I haven't been around any of the sites much here lately, so I didn't think to go to the main meta.

Answer (score 7):

Citizen Patrol has been extended to all mod flags, so if you have ever mod flagged, you will now get it.